# SyliusCmsPlugin with CKFinder

Tags: php, plugins, ckeditor4.x, sylius, ckfinder3

did anybody successfully integrated CKFinder to CMS plugin ?
I used ckfinder/ckfinder-symfony-bundle, got it installed, downloaded, assets installed, added to default
bitbag_sylius_cms_plugin configuration

```
fos_ck_editor:
    default_config: bitbag_sylius_cms_plugin
        configs:
            bitbag_sylius_cms_plugin:
                extraPlugins: 
                    - "media"
                    - "ckfinder" 
    plugins:
        ckfinder:
            path: "/bundles/cksourceckfinder/ckfinder/"
            filename: "ckfinder.js"
        
    twig:
        form_themes:
            - '@FOSCKEditor/Form/ckeditor_widget.html.twig'
```

so whole configuration looks like

```
fos_ck_editor:
    default_config: bitbag_sylius_cms_plugin
    configs:
        bitbag_sylius_cms_plugin:
            toolbar: bitbag_sylius_cms_plugin
            extraPlugins:
                - media
                - ckfinder
    plugins:
        media:
            path: /bundles/bitbagsyliuscmsplugin/js/ckeditor-plugins/media/
            filename: plugin.js
        ckfinder:
            path: /bundles/cksourceckfinder/ckfinder/
            filename: ckfinder.js
    toolbars:
        configs:
            bitbag_sylius_cms_plugin:
                - '@standard.clipboard'
                - '@standard.editing'
                - '@standard.links'
                - '@standard.insert'
                - '@standard.tools'
                - '@standard.document'
                - /
                - '@standard.basic_styles'
                - '@standard.paragraph'
                - '@standard.about'
        items:
            standard.insert:
                - Image
                - Media
                - Table
                - HorizontalRule
                - SpecialChar
    enable: true
    async: false
    auto_inline: true
    inline: false
    autoload: true
    jquery: false
    require_js: false
    input_sync: false
    base_path: bundles/fosckeditor/
    js_path: bundles/fosckeditor/ckeditor.js
    jquery_path: bundles/fosckeditor/adapters/jquery.js
    styles: {  }
    templates: {  }
    filebrowsers: {  }
```

but it crashes with errors in browser console and ckeditor is not visible
[image]

cheers,
Piotr